# appharbor 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: appharbor

when I go to my appharbor site I get a 502 Bad Gateway
in the logs I see

```
appharbor nginx xx.xx.xxx.xxx - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "Logplex/unknown" "source=nginx measure#http.response_time=0.000s measure#http.bytes.sent=300"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a problem on appharbors side